# using "possessive pronoun"

Tags: possessives, determiners

In English, we can say

- *"we went on holiday with some friends of ours"*

  or,
- *"we went on holiday with some friends of our own"*,

but we can say

> "we went on holiday with our some friends"

or not?

Comment: Yes, you can say this but the correct English is, "... some of our friends."

Comment: I don't much like "**some**" here, I'd stick to "**a few**".

Answer (score 1):

No. It is wrong to say 'Our Some Friends'. The best choice would be 'Some of our friends'. This is because, in this case 'Some' refers to a subset of 'All (of our friends)'. As if you are saying 'not ALL of them'.

You can, however, say 'Our MANY friends' or 'Our FEW friends' because these descriptions describe the total number of friends.

Likewise,

'Our friends are FEW' and 'Our friends are MANY' are fine. But 'Our friends are SOME' is not.